# Does the Local Storage have some kind of internal "optimization" by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage, web-storage

Is there any difference between:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 1);
```

and:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', true);
```

From the point of view of storage requirements? Is there any kind of value optimization carried out by the browser before actually storing data (i.e. compression)?

**Please note that** I'm assuming that Local Storage can handle any type of data and not just strings. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: *Note: Keep in mind that everything you store in any of the storages described in this page is converted to string using its .toString method before being stored. So trying to store a common object will result in string "[object Object]" to be stored instead of the object or its JSON representation. Using native JSON parsing and serialization methods provided by the browser is a good and common way for storing objects in string format.* FROM: [MDN Dom Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-strings that you store in localStorage are [converted to strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) before being stored. So true would be stored as "true", and 1 would be stored as "1".